# mutiple 'order by ' in doctrine 2 query

Tags: doctrine-orm

I want my doctrine 2 query below to have more than 1 **"order by"** category.

However, I noticed that doctrine 2 only supports the last last **"order by query"**  i.e:

```
 ->orderBy('u.qualityOfPictures', 'DESC');
```

Does anyone know whether doctrine 2 supports more than 1 "order by"

If so, what is the correct way to format it.

**my query**

```
$qb  =  $this->queryBuilder()
                      ->select(array('u'))
                       ->from('BaseModel\Entity\User','u')
                       ->orderBy('u.dateOfRegistration', 'DESC')
                        ->orderBy('u.qualityOfPictures', 'DESC');
```

thank you

Comment: [Order by multiple columns with Doctrine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575325/order-by-multiple-columns-with-doctrine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query builder allows you to add `order by` using the construction [`addOrderBy`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html):

```
          $qb  = $this->queryBuilder()
                      ->select(array('u'))
                      ->from('BaseModel\Entity\User','u')
                      ->orderBy('u.dateOfRegistration', 'DESC')
                      ->addOrderBy('u.qualityOfPictures', 'DESC');
```

The order in the generated SQL is the natural order: first goes `orderBy` and then the `addOrderBy` in the order you defined them in the query.

Comment: @PaulKendal please accept if it answered your question