# symfony doctrine 2 OneToMany - association to the inverse side field error

Tags: symfony, doctrine, associations, mappedby

I want to connect two entities

Dish that is in some DishCategory

Dish (category_id) with DishCategory (id)

There is an error:

The association AppBundle\Entity\Dish#categoryId refers to the inverse side field AppBundle\Entity\DishCategory#category_id which does not exist.

These are my entity classes

### Dish Entity

```
class Dish
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     private $id;

    /**
     *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity = "DishCategory",inversedBy="category_id",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id",referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     private $categoryId;
}
```

DishCategory Entity

---

```
class DishCategory
{

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Dish", mappedBy="category_id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id",referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     private $id;
}
```

In DishController I run this function to repository

```
$dishes = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Dish')->findAllAsArray();
```

And that how DishRepository looks

```
public function findAllAsArray()
{
    return $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->join('d.categoryId','c')
        ->select('d.id as id_dish','c.id as id_cat','d.price')
        ->orderBy('c.position', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('d.position', 'asc')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
    }
```

I have read many tutorials about OneToMany but still I cant find where is the problem :(

Still getting error:

> The association AppBundle\Entity\Dish#categoryId refers to the inverse
>   side field AppBundle\Entity\DishCategory#category_id which does not
>   exist.

:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess **category_id** is a foreign key. [Don't map foreign keys to fields in an entit](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/best-practices.html#don-t-map-foreign-keys-to-fields-in-an-entity) because:

> Foreign keys have no meaning whatsoever in an object model. Foreign keys are how a relational database establishes relationships. Your object model establishes relationships through object references. Thus mapping foreign keys to object fields heavily leaks details of the relational model into the object model, something you really should not do.

your DishCategory entity is the **Owning side** because it holds the foreign key. By the way update your code as below:

**Dish entity**

```
class Dish
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DishCategory", inversedBy="dishes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dish_category_id",referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     private $dishCategory;
}
```

**DishCategory entity**

```
class DishCategory
{

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     private $id;

     /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Dish", mappedBy="dishCategory")
      */
      private $dishes;

     public function __construct()
     {
         $this->dishes = new ArrayCollection();
     }
}
```

Then in your **DishRepository**

```
public function findAllAsArray()
{
    return $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->join('d.category','c')
        ->select('d.id as id_dish','c.id as id_cat','d.price')
        ->addOrderBy('c.position', 'asc')
        ->addOrderBy('d.position', 'asc')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)
    ;
}
```

But I don't see the point of doing a double orderBy because [multiple calls to orderBy do not stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11575396/2061624), use addOrderBy if you want to achieve this. And also Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY is not necessary, I guess, because you will have an array due to the custom query, not and entity.

Comment: Thank You. Well explained. More than I expected. That's great. Now I'm moving on. Thanks :)

Comment: Seems like the mapping configuration was an inconsistent. I updated the code

Comment: Works just fine;)