# Get last 10 rows with query builder and order them by another column

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a table called Invoice. It has 3 fields. id, createdAt and amount.
I am developing with Symfony PHP framework.
I want to create a query builder which returns the 10 last created rows and order them by amount.

Can I achieve this with query builder?
Thank you

EDIT:
I found a solution. It is a work around but in my case I think it is ok.
Basically I just make another query to get the last 10 rows and then put the ids in an array.

```
$subquery = $this->createQueryBuilder('invoice')
            ->orderBy('invoice.createdAt', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(3)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

        $idArray = [];
        foreach ($subquery as $item)
        {
            $idArray[] = $item->getId();
        }

        $invoices->where('i.id IN (:items)')
        ->setParameter('items', $idArray);
```

Then I just check if my original query ids are in this array.
Hope this helps someone in the future!

I tried this

```
$invoices->orderBy('i.createdAt', 'DESC')
                ->addOrderBy('i.amount', 'ASC')
                ->setMaxResults(10);
```

However this only orders them by createdAt. I am guessing I need to get the last 10 rows in the table in a different way and not with orderBy.

Comment: you need a subquery. essentially you probably want this: `select * from (select * from invoice order by created_at desc limit 10) t order by amount`. you can also do something like `select * from invoice i where i.id in (select i2.id from invoice i2 order by i2.createdAt desc limit 10) order by i.amount asc`, which is probably easier to achieve with querybuilder. for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637506/doing-a-where-in-subquery-in-doctrine-2

Comment: sorry how can I limit the subquery? When I use ->setMaxResults() it does nothing..

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced a similar situtation (ordering on multiple column).
Two soutions are proposed here : [Order by multiple columns with Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575325/order-by-multiple-columns-with-doctrine)

Either you can try to use two `addOrderBy()` instead of `orderBy()` and `addOrderBy()` , for instance :

```
$invoices->addOrderBy('i.createdAt', 'DESC')
                ->addOrderBy('i.amount', 'ASC')
                ->setMaxResults(10);
```

Or use the `add()` method, for instance :

```
$invoices->add('orderBy', 'i.createdAt DESC, i.amout ASC')->setMaxResults(10);
```

info on the add() method : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#low-level-api

Comment: if the orders are not in the same second - this is not what OP wants.